# wss url from rtm.start gives cannot create connection error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slack, slack-api

I am a newbie and trying to integrate my app with slack. I am using wss url that we get in the response from rtm.start and tried establishing connection through simple JS code and in response to it I get following error

```
{isTrusted: true, data: "{"type":"error","error":{"msg":"Cannot create connection","code":3,"source":"gs-bom-bcfd"}}", origin: "wss://cerberus-xxxx.lb.slack-msgs.com", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
```

when I use the wss url from response in tester tab of the following link https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start/test 
it works fine and I start getting events.

js code that I used is as below

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss URL");
ws.onopen = function(event) {
  console.log("WebSocket is open now.");
};
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("WebSocket message received:", event);
};
```

Note: I have been using same authentication token from both the places, So no difference in application scope.

can someone guide me on this what's wrong with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this issue that might help others too if they are stuck with any similar situation.

I am using the slack package from npm for integration to my react app and in the slack package in node_modules, it already is creating a socket connection in rtm.client-browser file so when I try to create connection from my code it gives error as already a connection using same wss url has been requested by slack.

do check networks tab for any duplicate connection requests.